# converting decimal to 32 bit binary

Tags: c, binary, decimal

Hi I have been giving an assignment for my programming in C class and a question im stuck on is this. 
"Prompts the user to enter a valid integer between 0 and
2147483647 inclusive, and then displays the converted
value as a 32-bit binary number with 1 space separating
each 8-bits in the binary value. If an invalid number
is entered (i.e < 0 or > 2147483647)"
it wants me to output the binary in 32 bit format such as 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011111 =31 with all of the 0's and spacing between each set of 8 and I am stuck.

```
 printf("enter a valid integer between 0 and 2147483647\n");
                 scanf("%d",&decimal);
                 fflush(stdin);
                 if (decimal>0||decimal<2147483647)
                   {while (decimal!=0)
                   {
                          remainder = decimal%2;
                          binary=(remainder*place)+binary;
                          decimal=decimal/2;
                          place=place*10;}
                   printf("%d",binary);}
```

this kinda works until the input is over 1000 then its gets messed up. unsure why as well.

Comment: Usually you'll need to post your attempt first (don't worry if it's wrong).

Comment: And `fflush`ing `stdin` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that numbers are stored *in binary* in memory, right? So you can just examine each bit, one by one, and print out the result as you go:

You can examine the bits using *bitwise operators*. You can create the binary number `1000 0000 0000 0000` from the number `1` by *left-shifting* the number 31 places: `1<<31`. You can then check if your number has the 32nd bit set with a  *bitwise-and*: `(1<<31) & decimal`. If the result is zero, then that bit was not set. If the result is non-zero, then the bit was set.

Assuming the single-bit value (this is usually called a *mask*) is stored in an `unsigned int`, you can check the 31st bit by right-shifting it once:

```
unsigned int mask = 1 << 31; // mask for 32nd bit
mask = mask >> 1; // move mask to 31st bit
if (mask & decimal != 0) {
  // 31st bit is set
}
else {
  // not set
}
```

Using an `unsigned int` is very important. If you use a normal (signed) `int`, then the `>>` operator has a different behavior. For unsigned numbers, when shifting right, the left-hand-side is padded with zeros. For signed numbers, the left-hand-side is instead padded with whatever value (0 or 1) was in the highest bit. So, if you had the *signed* binary value `1000 0000 0000 0000` and you shift it right 1 (`signed_mask >> 1`), then you would end up with `1100 0000 0000 0000` rather than `0100 0000 0000 0000`.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j, decimal;
    printf("enter a valid integer between 0 and 2147483647\n");
    scanf("%d",&decimal);
    fflush(stdin);
    // all signed integers are <= 2147483647, so just check if it's positive
    if (decimal>0) { 
        // create a "mask" to look at the 32nd bit
        // note that we use an unsigned mask!
        // this is important because we don't want
        // sign-extending when we shift to the next bit.
        unsigned int mask = 1<<31;
        for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
                // check current bit, and print
                char c = (decimal & mask) == 0 ? '0' : '1';
                putchar(c);
                // move down one bit
                mask >>= 1;
            }
            // print a space very 4 bits
            putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the condition `decimal>0||decimal<2147483647` in your code is *always true*. I think you meant to use `&&`, not `||`. However, `2147483647` is the maximum value for a signed 32-bit integer (2<sup>31</sup>-1), so it doesn't actually make sense to check the upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `binary` isn't big enough to hold 32 0's and 1's. You might notice that the maximum number allowed is about 10 decimal digits. That's all an `int` can store on most systems.

You might display each binary digit by itself as soon at it is computed, or store them in an array and display it all later.